# How to feed extracted MFCC features on a machine learning algorithm?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, deep-learning, mfcc

I have extracted 39 dimensional MFCC, Delta and Delta Delta parameters using MFCC and saved those parameters on a CSV file. This is the link to my CSV file https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TTnsGSGhdQBqo9AgXhK9k4GlNyhSvUm7

I have tried this to read data from the CSV file and Train SVM model. This is the right way? If not, how to feed those MFCC features for any learning algorithm?

```py
train_data = pd.read_csv('data/Chewing/train/ChewingTrain.csv')

x_train = train_data.iloc[:, 0:39]

y_train = train_data.iloc[:, -1]

clf = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', gamma='scale')

clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Comment: What algorithm are you trying to use? How is this related to TensorFlow?

Comment: I just want to learn how to feed those extracted mfcc values to a learning algorithm. For RNN based approach I think TensorFlow is best suited that's why I have used 'tensorflow' as a keyword.

Comment: I am slightly confused. What is the connection between Recurrent Neural Networks and Support Vector Machines here? What is wrong with the code that you posted?